# minimal requirements for specifying file paths in a cloud bucket

Tags: snakemake

I am very familiar with GCP but new to Snakemake.

I have a simple working example with a snakemake file that just has:

```
rule sed_example:
    input:
        "in{sample}.txt"
    output:
        "out{sample}.txt"
    shell:
        "sed 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM/' {input} > {output}"
```

This runs fine on my local machine with the command:

```
snakemake -s Snakefile --verbose --cores=1 out{1,2,3,4,5}.txt
```

If I run it without specifying the output filenames, I get the error:
WorkflowError:
Target rules may not contain wildcards. Please specify concrete files or a rule without wildcards.

But I guess that is expected.

Next, I want to run the same thing but have the files be in a GCP/GCS bucket.  I put the files there with gsutil rsync and I can even list them from inside a snakefile, if I use this code snippet inside the snakemake file, so my google auth setup seems fine:

```
from os.path import join
from snakemake.remote.GS import RemoteProvider as GSRemoteProvider
GS = GSRemoteProvider()
GS_PREFIX = "snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket"
samples, *_ = GS.glob_wildcards(GS_PREFIX + 'in{sample}.txt')
print(samples)
```

The input files are there:

```
$ gsutil ls gs://snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/
gs://snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/Snakefile
gs://snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/in1.txt
gs://snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/in2.txt
gs://snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/in3.txt
gs://snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/in4.txt
gs://snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/in5.txt
```

I was hoping it would be as easy as:

```
snakemake -s Snakefile --verbose --cores=1 --default-remote-provider GS --default-remote-prefix gs://snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/ out{1,2,3,4,5}.txt
```

but that gives me the error:

```
MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce out4.txt (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).
```

I guess ultimately I don't understand how Snakemake generates the absolute paths for files, as the auto-magic does not work for me.  I tried various ways to specify bucket/filename...

I tried:

```
snakemake -s Snakefile --verbose --cores=1 --default-remote-provider GS --default-remote-prefix gs://snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/ out{1,2,3,4,5}.txt
MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce out3.txt (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).
snakemake -s Snakefile --verbose --cores=1 --default-remote-provider GS --default-remote-prefix gs://snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/ gs://snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/out{1,2,3,4,5}.txt
ValueError: Bucket names must start and end with a number or letter.
```

I tried changing the inputs and/or outputs in the snakefile to         GS.remote("in{sample}.txt") instead of just "in{sample}.txt" and got various errors such as:

```
  File "/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/remote/GS.py", line 224, in parse
    if len(m.groups()) != 2:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

I also tried variations of:

```
GS.remote("gs://snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/in{sample}.txt")
GS.remote("snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/in{sample}.txt")
GS.remote("gs://snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/in1.txt")
GS.remote("snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/in1.txt")
```

here is the output of my most common error:

```
(snakemake) alex-mbp-923:snakemake-example $ snakemake -np --verbose --cores=1 --default-remote-provider GS --default-remote-prefix gs://snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket/ out{1,2,3,4,5}.txt
/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py:69: UserWarning: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/
  warnings.warn(_CLOUD_SDK_CREDENTIALS_WARNING)
/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py:69: UserWarning: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/
  warnings.warn(_CLOUD_SDK_CREDENTIALS_WARNING)
/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py:69: UserWarning: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/
  warnings.warn(_CLOUD_SDK_CREDENTIALS_WARNING)
/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py:69: UserWarning: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/
  warnings.warn(_CLOUD_SDK_CREDENTIALS_WARNING)
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
Building DAG of jobs...
Full Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 626, in snakemake
    success = workflow.execute(
  File "/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 655, in execute
    dag.init()
  File "/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 172, in init
    job = self.update(self.file2jobs(file), file=file, progress=progress)
  File "/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 1470, in file2jobs
    raise MissingRuleException(targetfile)
snakemake.exceptions.MissingRuleException: No rule to produce out1.txt (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).

MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce out1.txt (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).


(snakemake) alex-mbp-923:snakemake-example $ cat Snakefile
from os.path import join
from snakemake.remote.GS import RemoteProvider as GSRemoteProvider
GS = GSRemoteProvider()
GS_PREFIX = "snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket"
samples, *_ = GS.glob_wildcards(GS_PREFIX + '/in{sample}.txt')
print(samples)

rule sed_example:
    input:
        "in{sample}.txt"
    output:
        "out{sample}.txt"
    shell:
        "sed 'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM/' {input} > {output}"
```

What am I missing?  Clearly I am not specifying the paths correctly but I can't figure out what the correct way should be.

Specifying 
GS_PREFIX = "snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket"
vs 
GS_PREFIX = "gs://snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket"
doesn't seem to matter, and I guess that's OK.

Other examples I looked at:

```
https://github.com/bhattlab/bhattlab_workflows/blob/master/preprocessing/10x_longranger_GCP.snakefile
https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html
https://blog.liang2.tw/posts/2017/08/snakemake-google-cloud/
https://www.bsiranosian.com/bioinformatics/large-scale-bioinformatics-in-the-cloud-with-gcp-kubernetes-and-snakemake/
```

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the snakemake command the option --default-remote-prefix needs just "snakemake-cluster-test-02-bucket".
The rest is assumed, since you have GS value for --default-remote-provider option.
Boris